# How can I randomize the value of CSS attributes using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use jquery to make a css selector randomize one of its values on an html element. I've gotten as far as randomizing the selector for all of the elements (cycling through colors on a list border-left), however I want to randomize each individual list element at the same time.

Apologies if that's confusing (I'm confused by it myself), but you'll understand if you run the below code a few times and watch the border color change. Ideally, those border colors would all be different.

Thanks very much for any help.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
    .bars{
        border-left-style: solid; 
        border-left-width: 4px;
        padding-left: 10px;
    }

    ul{
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
        <ul>
            <li class="bars">
              <a>Marathon Men and Women</a>
            </li>   

            <li class="bars">
              <a>Marathon Men and Women</a>
            </li>   

            <li class="bars">
              <a>Marathon Men and Women</a>
            </li>   

            <li class="bars">
              <a>Marathon Men and Women</a>
            </li>   

            <li class="bars">
              <a>Marathon Men and Women</a>
            </li>   
         </ul>
</body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var colors = ["#CCCCCC","#333333","#990099"];                
      var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length);           
      $('.bars').css("border-left-color", colors[rand]);
    });
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RMR42/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jQuery.each() function to specify individual colors: http://jsfiddle.net/qaF24/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var colors = ["#CCCCCC","#333333","#990099"];                
    $('.bars').each(function() {
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length);
        $(this).css("border-left-color", colors[rand]);
    });
});
```

Comment: I know we're supposed to avoid 'thanks' as comments, but this is the best. I haven't used SO before and am blown away by the community. Thank you very much, and the same for everyone else.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/RMR42/1/

```
var colors = ["#CCCCCC", "#333333", "#990099"];
var bars = document.getElementsByClassName('bars');
for (var i = 0; i < bars.length; i++) {
    bars[i].style.borderLeftColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
}
```

Maybe a vanilla solution will help somebody. Faster, without more code.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery selector ('.bars') is selecting all elements of the class 'bar'. Of course it's going to set them all the same.

I would recommend instead assign an id to the parent element and then use the `.children()` selector to iterate through each `<li>` and assign a color.

something like

```
<ul id="bars">
        <li>
          <a>Marathon Men and Women</a>
        </li>   

        <li>
          <a>Marathon Men and Women</a>
        </li>   

        <li>
          <a>Marathon Men and Women</a>
        </li>   

        <li>
          <a>Marathon Men and Women</a>
        </li>   

        <li>
          <a>Marathon Men and Women</a>
        </li>   
     </ul>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var colors = ["#CCCCCC","#333333","#990099"],rand;                
  var ligroup = $('#bars').children();
  for (var i=0,len=ligroup.length;i<len;i++) {
       rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length);
       $(ligroup[i]).css("border-left-color", colors[rand]);
  }

});
</script>
```

Comment: What if there are more then one parent? Some children only?

Comment: there can't be more than one parent since it selects for the ID but there could be multiple levels of children, you'd have to adjust accordingly with further selectors. iterating through the DOM as your answer works better as a more general case but `getElementByClassName` is a bit slow.

Comment: True, but you wrote that case specifically for it to work with your limited code :)

Comment: It depends on whether OP was providing his code or an example, and whether OP will ever modify it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var bars = document.getElementsByClassName('bars');
for (var i = 0; i < bars.length; i++) {
    bars[i].style.borderLeftColor ="#"+genColor();
}
});
```

Random color generator for each Li : http://jsfiddle.net/RMR42/2/

you have to use some sort of looping through all the similar class elements if you want each individual to be different and random.

reference: https://gist.github.com/wfreeman/1158409

Comment: OP didn't want just any color, OP defined the colors.