# Randomize float css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I was wondering if there is a simple way to randomize the CSS "float" value for a given `.class` or `#Id`. Meaning, on every refresh it should randomly choose `float:left` or `float:right`.

Comment: if you can use javascript try Math.random(), then set the class randomly for each

Comment: Does it have to be pure CSS? Because I dont think its possible without using JavaScript

Comment: thank you both for the reply , no pure css, jquery, javascript or php is fine, as long as the posible ones are left and right, float none would ruin the layout i have in mind :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I randomize the value of CSS attributes using jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025496/how-can-i-randomize-the-value-of-css-attributes-using-jquery)

Comment: sorry David, I was actually looking throu Stack before posting my question, did not see this one, my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using jquery it's very easy, you first create a random boolean:

```
   var flt=Boolean(Math.floor(Math.random()*2));
```

and then you use that to determine if float should be left or right:

```
   $("#id").css('float',flt?'left':'right');
```

or

```
   if(flt) $("#id").css('float','left');
   else $("#id").css('float','right);
```

I made a [JSFiddle with a working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7ptdb7o8/1/)

Comment: Might as well just use `Math.random() > .5` as the condition

Comment: True @DJDavid98, would work as well, some of the other answers had an array with possible options for the float. the 2 could then be replaced with 'array.length' and be more flexible. In this case you obviously don't have to cast to a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

You can do following:

```
var items = ['right','left'];
var item = items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)];
$('#yourItem').css('float',item);
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5og6h490/)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work.
Create an array of float values
For each item in your class, get a random position in the array, and use this to set your flaot.

```
 <script>
    $(function(){
    var rFloat = ["left","right","none"];
    $(".youClass").each(function(){
         var xFloat = Math.floor(Math.random() * rFloat.length) + 1;  
          $(this).css("float",rFloat[xFloat]);
    });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Missing a semicolon, and why the `+ 0`?

Comment: This specify the start of a range. So in this case any number between 1 and the array length.... prob not be necessarily in this.

Comment: Also, OP is asking for `left`/`right` not `left`/`right`/`none`.

Comment: @DJDavid98, then they can remove it from the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP to generate an dynamic CSS file.

HTML code needed

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.php' />
```

Style.php

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");

echo '#float {';
echo ( (boolean)rand(0, 1) ? 'float:left;' : 'float:right;' );
echo '}';

?>
```